# Jade: Are the template files loaded per npm start?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, pug, template-engine

As in the title said, are the **jade** ***template files*** as is loaded, when I start my app server (e.g. via terminal `npm start`)?

If so, it would be less CPU consuming to use deeper template hierarchies, I suppose.

Comment: How are you rendering them? via `res.render('your-view')`?

Comment: yes, exactly. are there better means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View templates are compiled and cached (in production) when requested, not at startup.

To enable template caching when not in production mode you can enable by doing the following:

```
app.set('view cache', true);
```

See the [Express docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.set) for more information.

Comment: I suppose via the 'view cache' property for example?

Comment: Yes, I'll update my answer to include an code sample to enable it (even in development).